# Configuration SharePoint Workflow Manager Error: Fabric

Tags: workflow-manager

Helo together,

I want to use Workflows in SharePoint 2013, thats why I had to configure the SharePoint 2013 Workflow Manager. But if i want to complete the wizard I get the following error message:

> Windows Fabric configuration started. Running Windows Fabric
>   deployment. Program C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\FabricDeployer.exe exited with
>   error: Windows Fabric deployment failed. DeploymentValidator: warning:
>   The Fabric Data Collection Agent is disabled for this deployment. None
>   of the declared nodes is for the current machine.

**What was recommend to solve the problem:**

Check host file. I did this, no problems.

At: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525439/sharepoint-workflow-manager-installation-failure-none-of-the-declared-nodes-is
I found out, that I should check the ClusterManifest.*.xml but there are no Problems.

---

I could not solve the error, so I asked the question here. I have no idea to solve this.

It would be very nice if someone could help me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

did you comment the host file's entry for 127.0..? if yes then remove the entry and then try again.
https://blog.tallan.com/2013/05/15/workflow-manager-installation-error-adding-host-to-service-bus-farm-2/

Another approach is completely remove the Workflow Manager and try to re install it.

http://www.spjeff.com/2013/03/27/configuring-workflow-manager-1-0-on-sharepoint-2013-screenshots/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. 127.0.0 was allready commented with #. And the workflow manager still doesnt works. But if I delete the # before 127.0.. why should this solve the problem?

Comment: i am not sure why, but i can think, your DNS is not properly working thats why it need the host header entry. but glad it fix the issue.